# Error installing Azure Workflow Server during 2013 install

Tags: workflow, installation, azure

I am attempting to install the Azure Workflow Server on a SharePoint 2013 FE box using WPI in /offline mode, but the install fails. The FE is a Win2K8R2 box and is not a DC.

Here are the errors noted just before rollback begins:

1) In the WPI log file:

MSI (s) (1C:1C) [16:08:26:371]: Note: 1: 1722 2: DoFabricSetup 3: C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\MSIHiddenAppLauncher.exe 4: FabricSetup /operation:install /gac /trace:"C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log" /fabricDataRoot:"C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\" /traceBufferSizeInKB:128 /traceFileSizeInMB:128 /fabricPrincipal:"<>"

CustomAction DoFabricSetup returned actual error code 1 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

MSI (s) (1C:1C) [16:08:26:371]: Product: Windows Fabric -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action DoFabricSetup, location: C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\MSIHiddenAppLauncher.exe, command: FabricSetup /operation:install /gac /trace:"C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log" /fabricDataRoot:"C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\" /traceBufferSizeInKB:128 /traceFileSizeInMB:128 /fabricPrincipal:"<>"

2) In the Fabric Setup trace log:

2013-05-28 20:20:08.427,Info    ,6240,Common.ProcessUtility,CreateProcess Successful for CommandLine:logman start FabricTraces. ProcessId:4216 MainThreadId:2728 ProcessHandle:148

2013-05-28 20:20:09.379,Error   ,6240,FabricSetup.EventTraceInstaller,enable trace for session FabricTraces failed with exit code 2147943458.

2013-05-28 20:20:09.379,Error   ,6240,General.FabricSetup,Trace start result : false.

2013-05-28 20:20:09.379,Warning ,6240,General.FabricSetup,Installation failed. Calling uninstall.

There are no Google hits for "FabricTraces 2147943458" and I have no idea what this error code means.

Has anyone seen this during a 2013 install? Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5+ (!) weeks investigating this with MS tech support, we finally determined that the Windows Service "Performance Logs & Alerts" was set as Disabled startup type. Changing that service to Manual startup type allowed the installer to complete.

This problem was indicated nowhere in the logs or any other trace as far as I can tell. There was no indication this was a requirement for installation anywhere either. I had to provide disk images to MS tech support so that they could reproduce the problem before they could figure out what was wrong.

Seems like the installer should have adjusted the service as needed to proceed. I mean, an installation was underway, so just fix it, right? Better error messages and requirements documentation would have helped too.

Comment: Thanks it saved my time.Thanks a lot for the timely solution

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue which brought me here. Solution was different so I'll document it.

Environment: Windows 10 Enterprise (1607), Installed as English language and Finnish locale/region (**this is key**)

Installing: `webpicmd /install /products:servicebus_1_1`

Fails with

```
Started installing: 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM'
Install completed (Failure): 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM'
WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0 : Failed.
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
DependencyFailed : Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1
DependencyFailed : Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1
DependencyFailed : Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798)
```

Fabric Setup log in `C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces` had:

```
2017-02-28 13:51:33.270,Info    ,14672,Common.ProcessUtility,CreateProcess Successful for CommandLine:logman create trace FabricTraces -p {cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8} -o "C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces\fabric_traces_131327634932704232" -bs 128 -f bin -max 128 -cnf 00:00:00 -v nnnnnn. ProcessId:10164 MainThreadId:14576 ProcessHandle:21c
2017-02-28 13:51:33.286,Error   ,14672,FabricSetup.EventTraceInstaller,create trace for session FabricTraces failed with exit code 2147614725.
2017-02-28 13:51:33.286,Error   ,14672,General.FabricSetup,Trace sinks installation result : false.
2017-02-28 13:51:33.286,Warning ,14672,General.FabricSetup,Installation failed. Calling uninstall.
```

Error code `2147614725` is `0x‭80020005‬`, which is a VB error for Date format mismatch. One of the logman parameters is `-cnd 00:00:00` which looks like time formatting string to me.

I changed my local admin regional settings to en-US, but that didn't help even after restart and full login as that user (date & time displayed correctly, also `time /t` on command line).

**Solution**

What finally helped was in Control Panel, "**Change date, time, or number formats**" -> "**Administrative**" -> (Welcome screen and new user) "**Copy settings**"; there I copied the current user to both, "Welcome screen" and "New user" as `display: en-US; input: fi-FI; format: en-US; location: US`

I hope this helps some other unfortunate soul.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't... :(

Comment: Try making all the settings into en-US and then also rebooting before restarting the installation. It's been a long time and I have only faint memory about this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me either. I had to install all the prerequisites manually from the temporary directory where WPI downloads its required setup files. When it comes to Workflow Manager refresh, i copied the .msi file form that temporary directory and ran below command by after placing it in any other drive and pointing that path in my PowerShell. It installed the WFM. Then i updated it smoothly from WPI.

.\Workflow_Manager.msi IACCEPTEULA=yes WEBPI=1